# EPUB 3.0 - Template

Tags: epub

I am working on building a semi-complex EPUB and I think it would be more beneficial / ultimately faster to write the EPUB by scratch in a text editor than to try and export with some automated program like Indesign or Vellum and massage the XHTML into a semblance of human form.  Does anyone know of a solid EPUB 3 template I can download where all the files have been set up and I simply need to write in the correct paths and declare the items?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might check out the answer to this question: http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1183/what-is-the-minimum-required-content-for-a-valid-epub . If that isn't what you're looking for, could you go into more detail about what you need in your template?

Comment: As a side note, InDesign does a reasonable job of generating the XHTML, provided that styles have been used properly throughout and all objects are anchored.